# Compare multiple domains in Excel sheet data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two cells in Excel.

Cell 1 contains domain names (this could be multiple domain names separated by a semicolon). In cell 2 users should only enter an email address associated with the domains in cell 1.

[image]

In cell 1 there could be two, three, etc. domains.

How can I achieve this using data validation?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? You want to prevent them from using an email provider that is not in your list?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming users can only enter 1 email adres in Cell2:

First step would be to isloate the email provider from the emailadres. Luckely email adresses are configured neatly, using the `@` to seperate the email name from the email provider. We want to find the exact location of the `@`, for that we can use `=Find("@",C2)` Where C2 is your cell 2.

In `abc@aaa.com` the result of `=Find("@",C2)` will be 4, as the `@` is located at the fourth position of the string.

Once we know where the `@` is located we can extract the domain using a combination of `Right()`, `Len()` and `Trim()` like this: `Right(Trim(C2),Len(Trim(C2))-Find("@",Trim(C2))` Where the `Trim()`function is used to remove any leading or trailing spaces.

In the same example of `abc@aaa.com` the formula evaluates to the following:

- `-Find("@",Trim(C2)` evaluates to `-4`
- `Len(Trim(C2))`evaluates to 11, as there are 11 characters in the original adres.
- `Len(Trim(C2))-Find("@",Trim(C2)` thus evaluates to `11 - 4` which is `7`
- `Right(Trim(C2),7)` will take the first 7 characters from `C2` **from right to left**, resulting in `aaa.com`

To see if `aaa.com` is present in C1 we can use `Find()` with an error handler `Iserror()` combined within an `If()` statement: `If(Iserror(Find("aaa.com",C1)),0,1)` This will return `0` in case there is no match, and `1` in case there is a match.

To combine everything together we replace the `"aaa.com"` in the formula above with the first formula, resulting in: `If(Iserror(Find(Right(Trim(C2),Len(Trim(C2))-Find("@",Trim(C2)),C1)),0,1)`